# Dos2unix not working when trying to silence command

Tags: python

I was calling dos2unix from within Python this way:

```
call("dos2unix " + file1, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
```

However to silence the Unix output, I did this:

```
f_null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
call("dos2unix " + file1, shell=True, stdout=f_null , stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This doesn't seem to work. The command isn't being called anymore as the diff that I perform on the file fails (did a `diff -y file1 file2 | cat -t` and could see the line endings hadn't changed).

Comment: What is `file2`?  `dos2unix` does in-place editing by default.

Comment: file2 is the file I am comparing file1 against. It has Unix line endings as it is generated on the box. However, there is a chance that file1 doesn't.

Comment: You have `stdout` twice in the second example.

Comment: Sorry - made a mistake. Fixed that

Comment: Cannot reproduce, either version works fine for me. Try replacing the `dos2unix` call with something more easily trackable, like `touch testfile`.